Show full 90 minutes instead of 1:30
I have in this code:
label_time.Text = time.ToString("mm");

and it shows only up to 60 minutes and for the remaining 30 minutes starts from 0 and in the end it shows 30. How do I make it so it shows 90 instead of 30?
I already tried multiple things but I can't find the right way to do it.

We don't know the type of time which makes it hard to help. A [mcve] really helps to make this clearer...

What is the type of the time, and what does it represent? Please edit the question and add these clarifications.

It sounds like what you're looking for is the TotalMinutes property.
The mm format string instead formats the number of minutes per hour (ie, what would be displayed normally) and is used for displaying the full time span value, not for any kind of arithmetic.
